Current Red Heifer Events
I'm not quite sure this is the right place to ask, but I am hearing lots more chatter (than usual) about Red Heifers in Israel/Jerusalem lately.
I don't trust any sources I know of, but I do trust Mi Yodeya's community to be able to procure and vet good sources.
What's going with the 13(?) supposed Red Heifers in Jerusalem? Full info please.

I haven't seen any :(

@יהושעק where have you looked? Or are you saying you are the one they are going to bring them to when the time comes? :) Shavua tov and moadim lesimcha achi

I live and work in Jerusalem and haven't seen any yet. Interesting how a google search brings up sources as varied as Al Jazeera and The Temple Institute. Enjoy the rest of Pesach, ach sheli!

Some links: https://m.facebook.com/story.php?id=100048683003319&story_fbid=818006216498804&locale=he_IL, https://www.youtube.com/live/xfRSMtBkuFs?si=YJqvZX2a6-U875PB

@יהושעק not surprising at all. The muslim world take it as given that Oct 7th is a response to something to do with Red Heifers. Christians are going mad about it too because something something antichr*st

If you are really interested in this, reach out to Rabbi Chaim Richman.

Every few years there's excitement over the finding of a potential red heifer. The current interest is mostly driven by anti-Israel conspiracists, from what I've seen. They're under the impression there's an active effort to rebuild the Third Temple and this is part of the plot.
